# iOS hide keyboard on action

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a form that submits information from two text fields to Parse when the submit button is pressed and calls this action but I cannot get the keyboard to hide when the button is pressed and can use some help. Here is my code currently:

```
-(IBAction)PurchaseSubmitAction:(id)sender{
    PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Purchase"];
    gameScore[@"name"] = FullName.text;
    gameScore[@"phone"] = PhoneNumber.text;
    [gameScore saveInBackground];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [_Purchase setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"Load");
}
```

How can I have the keyboard clear? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 1):

Try `[self.view endEditing:YES]` where `self` is an instance of `UIViewController`, or keep track of the focused `UITextField` and use `[self.trackedTextField resignFirstResponder]` instead. `sender` in your code is an instance of `UIButton` which is not the `firstResponder` in this case.